# Can I limit wall clock time available for process on Solaris?

Tags: solaris, cpu-usage, timeout, resource-management, solaris-11

I would like (many) processes to be killed if still running after certain amount of time after execution. First I have thought that Solaris’ *resource management* is perfect tool for the job, as it seems to be natural for enforcing limits on groups of processes. So i have set up a project

`my_project:1000:testing project:::project.max-cpu-time=(priv,18000,signal=XCPU,syslog=err);rcap.max-rss=2651953561;task.max-cpu-time=(priv,30,signal=XCPU),(priv,90,signal=KILL)`

However the `*.max-cpu-time` resource controls seem to be counting time spent during computation only, so that e.g. program waiting for an input would be running infinitely.